# Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. (Swift iOS)

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is a block of code I'm using in my Xcode project. I'm trying to access data from my firestore database, however this block of code keeps on bringing up the error:

> Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server.  Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly

It's only this block of code that brings up the error. When I delete it, it's fine and the error goes away (but obviously the code won't be executed), and I really have no idea how to fix it.

```
Database.database().reference().child("cPosts").observe(.value)
  { (snapshot) in
      if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]
      {
          for data in snapshot
          {
              self.posts.removeAll()
              print(data)
              if let postDict = data.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
              {
                  let key = data.key
                  let post = CompPost(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                  self.posts.removeAll()
                  self.posts.append(post)
              }
          }
      }
      
      self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged with `google-cloud-firestore`, but your code is accessing the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API for one will not work on the other.

So if you are indeed using Cloud Firestore, update your code to use the API to read from *that* database as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen